# How change column names randomly in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am struggling to show different views of gridview with database values. Here is my requirement.

**Database Table:**
[image]

I need to show one drop downlist with three values 1,2,3. If user selects 3 i Need to show a grid like below

[image]

Age,AnnualSales and Assortment are names which are coming dynamically from database.

High,Medium and Core  all are values

Here my question is I need to show same attribute names.

Like If the name changes from "Assortment" to "Location" I need to show it in different page index .

In page index 2 i need to show like below.

[image]

Please help with solution

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be, generating columns in codebehind. e.g.

```
BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.HeaderText = "HeaderText";
bf.SortExpression = "Datafield";
bf.DataField = "Datafield";
GridView1.Columns.Add(bf);
```

One could write own TemplateClasses if required. There are lot of examples over net.
one would be

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx

Tweak column headers or columns of gridview as required.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very well by setting the property dynamically.

```
GridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Location";
```

I have worked pretty well using GridViews and databound controls in most dynamic ways.